# Using a URL parameter in route angular on sidebar

Tags: angular

I would like for the links on my sidebar to be dynamically generated based on the page URL / various service data.

That is to say: If I am on a property page `~/meters/meter/54321`, I would like to click on a link on the sidebar that will send me to `~/meters/meter/54321/overview`.

(Bonus points: If I am **not** on a property page, I would like the option not to show up on the sidebar, but first things first.)

Note that I have two different ways to be getting the `id` - either through a `MeterService` or via the `paramMap`.

When I'm doing this on a normal component/routing module, `/meters/meter/:id/overview` resolves perfectly to `/meters/meter/54321/overview`, and I'm able to create a simple `routerlink` from the page.

The issue is that `:id` is not resolving to the `paramMap id`, rather, it is trying to send me to `/meters/meter/:id/overview`.

Is there something special about a sidebar that makes this work differently? Should I be importing something else?

Thank you!

`component.ts:`

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MeterService } from "../../shared/services/meter.service";

declare interface RouteInfo {
    path: string;
    title: string;
}
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
    { path: '/meters', title: 'Property List' },
    { path: '/meters/add', title: 'Add Property'},
    { path: '/meters/meter/:id/overview', title: 'Property Overview'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  menuItems: any[];
  meter: string;
  id: string;

  constructor(private meterService: MeterService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.meterService.currentMeter.subscribe(meter => {this.meter = meter; this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);})
  }
```

`component.html:`

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
                <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's assuming we are on page `~/meters/meter/54321`, we can navigate to `~/meters/meter/54321/overview` with

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="./overview">
            ...
</a>
```

or

```
routerLink="overview"
```

or even

```
[routerLink]="['overview']"
```

We know how to navigate to a child route. But how to display this  tag only on a specific page ? The core of the solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260402.

The idea is to [listen to router events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular) in your sidebar component and for each route change, hide or display the  (with for example an NgIf directive).

Comment: This is actually interesting: for some reason when I do that (and I had tried it before), clicking from the sidebar sends me to `/meters/overview`, and I'm trying to now figure out why it's not treating `/meters/meter/54321` as the current page.

Comment: It seems like it was a routing issue. Thank you!

Comment: Fine, note also that i've give you some hints to handle your 'bonus point' ;)